# Error when calling SQLPackage 'publish' with TargetDatabaseName or tdn argument

Tags: arguments, sql-server-data-tools, sqlpackage

As the SQLPackage manual [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#bkmk_target_params) when calling `publish` action, we have the argument `TargetDatabaseName` or `tdn` (in section `Target Parameters`)

But when adding this parameter to SQLPackage call, I got the error saying that the argument is not valid.

Example:

```
SQLPackage.exe 
  /a:Publish 
  /SourceFile:"Path\to\My\CompiledDbProjectFile.dacpac"       
  /TargetUser:"SomeLoginName"  
  /TargetPassword:"SomePassword" 
  /TargetServerName:"SomeSQLServerInstance" 
  /TargetDatabaseName="SomeDatabase" 
  /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=true 
  /p:DropRoleMembersNotInSource=false 
  /p:DropPermissionsNotInSource=false 
  /p:DropObjectsNotInSource=false
```

Is that a bug? How can we work around for that?

Currently I have to use the /tcs:"The connections tring goes here"

Comment: Could you give an example of the arguments you are passing to SqlPackage? Note that arguments should look something like "SqlPackage.exe /a:publish /tdn:mydb /tsn:(localhost) /sf:myfile.dscpac". For overriding deployment properties you use the format "/p:CreateNewDatabase=true"

Comment: @KevinCunnane I have added the sample call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is wrong

```
/TargetDatabaseName="SomeDatabase"
```

The correct one should be

```
/TargetDatabaseName:"SomeDatabase"
```

Cheers